# httpd generate SSLCertificateChainFile

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl

I am looking for how to configure ssl in my web servers. I have used the following command to generate certificate file and certificate file.

openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout server.key -out server.crt

But I'm not sure for Certificate chain file. Could anyone let me know how to generate SSLCertificateChainFile

regards,
SP

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a self signed certificate with the above command. You will never have a Certificate chain in such a scenario, you simply use the privateKey server.key and the self-signed certificate server.crt and that's it.

Comment: Moreover, in circumstances where a chain file applies (ie, when you're getting your CSR signed by a third-party SSL certification service), the chain file is provided by the third-party service; it's not something you can create under any meaningful circumstances.